# SDL - Blitting an Array of SDL_Rect

Tags: c, arrays, sdl-2

Having trouble blitting an image in SDL2. I built an array of *SDL_Rect* using *malloc* and attributed to each member the usual x,y,w (width), and h (height) variables, but the images simply won't show up. Curiously, when I try blitting outside of a *for* loop by directly referencing the index of the element, it seems to work. Any idea what's going on?

```
//Not Working
int number =5;
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
          SDL_BlitScaled(myImage, NULL, mySurface, &(myElements[i]));
 }

//Works Perfectly
SDL_BlitScaled(myImage, NULL, mySurface, &(myElements[0]));
```

**Edit:** Ended up forgetting this part. Here's how the array is being generated:

```
SDL_Rect *myElements;

myElements = (SDL_Rect * ) malloc (number * sizeof(SDL_Rect));
generateGroup(myElements, number, 10, 10, 180, 30);
```

The function I am calling there looks like this:

```
void generateGroup(SDL_Rect* elementArray, int numberElements, int posX, int posY, int width, int height) {

int i;

for(i = 0; i < numberElements; i++) {
    elementArray[i].x = posX;
    posX =  posX + width + 1;
    elementArray[i].y = posY;
    elementArray[i].w = width;
    elementArray[i].h = height;
 }
}
```

To describe the issue more precisely, the image literally only appears when I blit outside the *for* loop. As for the index, in addition to 0, I have also tried 1 and 2, and both worked.

Comment: It would be better to provide a [mcve] in case the problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: [From @anddero] 1. Does the function succeed? It returns 0 on success and negative values on failure.
2. Have you tried indices other than 0 outside the loop?
EDIT: Double-check your x, y, w, h values just in case.